# How to inject a route parameter into _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a multitenant web app using ASP.Net Core v1.1.0.  A single user may belong to multiple tenants (ie - an area manager who oversees multiple stores.)  A user should also be able to go to the site and see some basic marketing views without logging in or having access rights to any tenant, but the functionality would be greatly limited.

Structurally, my project has not evolved much from the default ASP.Net Core MVC template so far...

In `Startup.cs`, I have defined my routes as follows to attempt to use subdomains to define which store the user is attempting to log into.  "DEMO" would indicate that the user should only see the marketing views:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{tenant=DEMO}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Since I have done that, the variable `tenant` can be magically used in a controller action definition like this, and it works fine:

```
public IActionResult Contact(string tenant)
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page for " + tenant + ".";

    return View();
}
```

But I use `_Layout.cshtml` as a wrapper that contains most of the site navigation and some personalized elements, and I would like to do things like disable most of the navigation for the DEMO tenant and display a store-specific logo for all other tenants.  Since to the best of my knowledge there is no controller associated with `_Layout.cshtml`, I need a different way of injecting this string.  I have tried adding the following line to `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@inject System.String tenant
```

and I get the error `InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'System.String' has been registered.`  This leads me to believe that I need to add something to the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`, but I don't know what I'm doing and have not been able to find any similar code samples online.  I am visualizing something like this:

```
services.AddScoped<ITenantFactory, MySeeminglyUnnecessaryFactory>();
```

but even then, I don't know how to get the `tenant` route parameter to the factory, or how to go about implementing that.  If I can just find a canned method of passing in the string, I'm sure I can work with that to do what I need to do as far as changing the look and feel of the layout, and I feel pretty comfortable restricting user access at the controller level.  Thanks in advance for any advice or ideas!

Comment: FYI - A guy named Ben Foster is putting out some great blog posts about multi-tenancy in ASP.NET Core. I've found these to be extremely useful. You can find them here: http://benfoster.io/blog/tagged/multi-tenancy

Comment: Good call!  I actually found his blog while I was researching this, and I looked into the SaasKit that he recommends.  I may wind up giving it a try, although there are still a lot of user-specific permissions that I need to consider in addition to just the tenant, so I'm leaning toward a custom solution at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the View Context:

```
Hello user of @(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["tenant"])!
```

source:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/19331f95326b18bd6f0400526074da934bf65cf0/test/WebSites/RazorPagesWebSite/HelloWorldWithRoute.cshtml

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/RazorPageBase.cs